# Почему метод hover в jquery меняет свойство элемента навсегда?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
window.onload = function() {
  $('.box').hover(
    function () {
      $('.box').css('background', 'white');
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: потому что ты сам жестко прописываешь `.css(` что жестко прописывает  атрибут `style` у элемента.... А `hover` тут не при чём

Comment: Сначала цвет элемента серый, потом при первом наведении стает белый. Так почему hover не при чем?

Comment: ты читать умеешь? см. выше

Comment: ну плюс к тому, hover принимает две функции - одна срабатывает на вход курсора в элемент, другая на выход..... на вход ты написал, на выход - нет (например чтоб сбросить стиль)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Во-первых `$('.box').css('background', 'white');` равносилен вот такой записи:

  ```
  <sometag style="background: white">Тут текст какой-то</sometag>
  ```

  то есть жестко прописывается атрибут `style`.
- Во-вторых `hover` в вашем варианте (т.е. вида `hover(handlerInOut(eventObject)`)
  устанавливает функцию `handlerInOut` в качестве обработчика обоих событий (mouseenter и mouseleave). Соответственно вы постоянно ставите `style` - вошёл курсор мыши в элемент или вышел.

Можно воспользоваться вариантом `hover(handlerIn(eventObject), handlerOut(eventObject)):`, где одна функция отвечает за вход (mouseenter), другая за выход (mouseleave) мыши с контура элемента.

Ну и классы лучше писать сразу в *CSS* и манипулировать чисто ими:

```js
$('.box').hover(function () {      
    $(this).addClass('test');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('test');
});
```

```css
.box {
  background: green;
}

.test {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">234243</div>
```

---

Кстати, `$( selector ).hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )` — это просто сокращенная запись вот такого вида:

```
$(selector).mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut);
```